# jquery - custom swipe gesture

Tags: jquery, mobile, swipe

I'm looking for a custom swipe gestures.
I DON'T want to use any plugin. (There are many out there)
I want to have my own script for this.

I wrote a script for a slider which I want to add mobile swipe gesture without plugin, just like flexslider, owlcarousel, ...  They have the gestures within their script.

Also I would like that the gesture follows the finger/mouse (like the examples above).  Not just do the action after the swipe has been done.

Is there any script out there for this?
THX

Comment: read more about [_touch events_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your own script, why you dont make one? 
Such a script by others which is quite good and tested is a plugin. The advantage is you are likely not to have issues in different devices if you use such a code.

You can extract that part from any available plugins but I dont know why you need to do that. Such available codes are reasonably small in minified versions.

Comment: I want to make one, but I currently have no idea how & where to start to achieve/approach this.

Comment: What you want is not a question to answer here. 
Then, why not use a plugin? It is already made by somebody who knows how and where to start.